# adb Goes from Authorized to Unauthorized after Booting into Recovery Mode

Tags: android, adb

I have a Pixel 2 connected to my computer via a USB cable. I follow the process on the phone to authorize the computer. When I run the `adb devices` command on my computer, the device shows as authorized. I then run the `adb reboot bootloader` and enter Recovery Mode. When I rerun `adb devices`, the device now shows up as unauthorized.

Is something changing when the device enters Recovery Mode? Is there a way to simply authorize from within Recovery Mode? Or do I need to be doing something different?

Comment: The authorization state is stored in your user data on the phone. Does the recovery have access to your [encrypted] user data partition?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that definitely sounds like it could be the issue. Is there a way to check if the bootloader has access?

Comment: Not the bootloader but the recovery OS can get access. Install or boot a matching TWRP recovery and you should be asked for a password if you want to access/mount user data (if you have set a system password/PIN/pattern).